# how to get city name from latitude and longitude using google api for ios

Tags: ios, location, google-api

I am using the following URl to get Address for my app

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=43.655958,-79.598459&output=csv

But i am getting response as  "610,0,0,0"

Can any one suggest correct URL to get the data

Comment: AFAIK Google does not offer reverse geolocation services. Even if it did, fetching data from Maps without actually displaying a map in your age in a certain way is a breah of their license agreement. You'd have to display a big map along with the name of that city you fetched or they might simply block your server from accessing any Google API at all.

Comment: Ok, they do offer reverse geocoding ([Check it out](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)), but you still gotta display a map.

Answer (score 2):

You can see an example of such reverse geocoding here:

http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

I don't know if that can be done with the API specific for iOS, but you could have that in a page if you can embed one into your app.

Notice, though, that you need to display a map in your app along with the name of the city, or display the city in a map in your page, otherwise it's a breach of their license agreement.